# How to put code tags inside of quill pre tags

Tags: codeblocks, quill

I am trying to format quill `pre` tags with `code` blocks in them for formatting purposes.

So, for example, I want to have this:

```xml
<pre>
  <code>
    ...my code
  </code>
</pre>
```

Quill, by default, will **get rid of anything** you add to the DOM directly, so you have to do it in Quill.

I found [this](https://github.com/quilljs/quill/issues/2189#issuecomment-411692250), with this potential code, but it does not add code blocks. It does not really do anything.

```js
var BlockEmbed = Quill.import('blots/block/embed');

class CustomCode extends BlockEmbed {
    static create(value) {
        let { lang, content } = value;
        let node = super.create(value);
        const code = document.createElement('code');
        code.setAttribute('class', lang);
        code.textContent = content;
        node.appendChild(code);
        return node;
    }

    static value(node) {
        return {
            lang: node.firstChild.getAttribute('class'),
            content: node.firstChild.innerText
        };
    }
}
CustomCode.blotName = 'code-custom';
CustomCode.tagName = 'pre';

Quill.register('modules/CustomCode', CustomCode);

var editor = new Quill("#editor", {
    modules: {
        syntax: true
    },
    theme: "bubble"
});
```

Any ideas, or am I missing something?

Comment: Hi, did you manage to solve this?

Comment: I honestly switched from quill, but you can use this buggy code... https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-ggvuuy?file=index.ts

Comment: What are you switching to? Thanks for the code! :D

Comment: https://github.com/github/markdown-toolbar-element

Answer (score 1):

You almost got it right.

In order to get it working one just need to:

- Register it a bit differently as `Quill.register(CustomCode);`
- Adjust `CustomCode` class to reflect the fact that the `create` method takes a string as an input and the `value` method should return the text content inside the `code` tag
- Adjust toolbar of a newly created editor to make sure we have a button providing us that new functionality
- Style that button a bit

I've prepared a [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-rx8kuc?file=index.ts) on StackBlitz to illustrate these points.

In order to try out the "custom code" functionality, click the "Code" button in the editor's toolbar and paste/type your snippet, then hit ok.

Here's a sample snippet: `function something() {console.log('It works');}`

If we inspect the DOM tree, we can see what you initially envisioned:
[image]

Comment: I am not sure what you did here. 1.) Highlightjs does not work 2.) The code button does not allow you to edit code... there should be inline-editing and not the awkward popup.   While this works, you answered half the question... The lang and the content are important for highlightjs. The code block should work as expected...

Comment: Well, the provided solution satisfies exactly what you initially requested (having `code` with some code inside `pre`). You didn't mention any additional requirements on the editing capabilities, language preference, and syntax highlight. Please, provide clear acceptance criteria so that we can come to a consensus.

Comment: Most importantly, could you, please, explain why the built-in code editing feature doesn't work for you? Quill has it out of the box, however, it uses `span` tags to highlight tokens.

Comment: HI Viacheslav.  Everything is on one line, that is the problem.  I cannot change that.  Fix that and I will accept the answer. ---  It was not clear how the code would be added, that is fair to say and I can't penalize for that.  However, I *assumed* (my problem) that no other feature would change, there would be no need to add a code block because everything would use just existing **pre** tags and we would add a **code** block inside them.  Everything would work the same.  Honestly, if Highlightjs is now disabled, that defeats the purpose of this problem.

Comment: I re-read the question, you technically answered the question, you just got rid of syntax highlighting.  So, I go one step forward, two steps backwards.  If you could help me not get rid of that, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Ok, if I understand it correctly you'd like to have the same exact functionality for syntax highlight as in the original Quill editor but with `span` tags generated by highlight.js replaced with `code` tags, is that correct?
If not, could you, please, update the sample markup in the question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225884/discussion-between-viacheslav-moskalenko-and-jonathan).

Comment: @Jonathan, please, check my last comment in the chat when you have a chance.